# How to layer (transparent) materials?

Tags: materials, transparency, render-layers, render-passes

I am generating layered patterns using procedural textures. that is easy enough in a single material using `mix shader` nodes.

[image]

what I would like to achieve though is to be able to render this, with each pattern as a separate *pass*, so that I can make manual adjustments to each individual layer in photoshop afterwards.

so my first thought was to simply split up the node setup into two different materials:

[image]

as you can see, this does not work. I would like to understand why, and what the correct approach would be.

the only alternative I was able to came up with, is to write a script that renders the object several times, but only with one material assigned. afterwards I'd have to combine the separate output files in a layered photoshop file.

---

I'm using the blender 2.8 beta, by the way.

Comment: Maybe you could render the layer with that object for both textures separately and then render a "clown pass" to be able to change between them in photoshop...

Answer (score -1):

I know this is 2 years late, but I found a way to do it.
If I'm reading this right, you're asking if you plug the facing node from a layer weight and into a constant color ramp, you then get a split layer between the first and second shader.

By moving the white value around, you can move the depth of the layer change:

[image]

The example here is a lamp that is using a glass shader and a emissions shader mixed together, using this node structure:

[image]